# (matlabcontrol library) How to send matrix from Java to Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, matlabcontrol

How can I send with the [MatlabControl JMI Wrapper](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html) a 2D matrix or 1D matrix (vector) from Java to a Matlab script? For example, the Matlab script takes as argument a 2D matrix A or a 1D matrix (vector) a.

Second, Does Java wait until Matlab has finished the execution? If no, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Seems useful here : [https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html]

Comment: @NikhilChilwant Thanks but I'm talking about MatlabControl JMI Wrapper.